# django: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found

Tags: django, math, unicode, model

I'm getting this error when trying to sum up two int values:

```
if dups.count() > 0:
        for item in dups:
            pi.quantity = pi.quantity+item.quantity
```

both pi and dups are instance of same model:

```
class PurchaseItem(models.Model):
    picture = models.ForeignKey(Picture, null=False)
    paperType = models.ForeignKey(paperType, null=False)
    printSize = models.ForeignKey(printSize, null=False)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1, validators=[validators.MinValueValidator(1)])
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=8)
    dateCreated = models.DateTimeField(null=False)
    sessionKey = models.ForeignKey(Session, to_field="session_key", null=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id
```

Why is int not good enough?

if I wrap the values with str() or use their .**str**() representation, it doesn't do quite what I need. 1 and 1 will before 11 instead of 2.

Comment: Is one of these values submitted by request.GET? If so, all items from a from the get dict are strings and you're going to have to explicitly convert it to an int.  ftr request.POST does the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, `item.quantity` is an integer, and `pi.quantity` is unicode.

I'm guessing `pi.quantity` was assigned a string previously (which django will convert upon db save), but it won't return the coerced value until you instantiate the class again. The value is cached according to some shell sessions.

Just do `pi.quantity = int(pi.quantity) + item.quantity` or look to where `pi.quantity` was defined and use integers instead!

Answer (score 4):

Your code :
    def **unicode**(self):
        return self.id

Should be:
    def **unicode**(self):
        return unicode(self.id )

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
if dups.count() > 0:
    for item in dups:
        pi.quantity = pi.quantity.to_python()+item.quantity.to_python()
```

This will probabaly raise the same error, but it is worth a try. Another (horrible horrible horrible) option is to do the following:

```
if dups.count() > 0:
    for item in dups:
        pi.quantity = int(str(pi.quantity))+int(str(item.quantity))
```

But that should not be done unless at last resort, and even then still not, as it covers up the actual issue which will probabaly cause more serious problems further on down the road.

By any chance, would it be possible to post a full stacktrace?

Comment: to_python() throws 'unicode' object has no attribute 'to_python'

Answer (score -1):

Just change last line

**from**

`return self.id`

**to**

`return str(self.id)`